# "Such a bad behavior" or "Such bad behavior"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-choice

> "I can’t believe he did that - I’ve never seen______ bad behavior!"

If there are two choices: "such" and "such a," which one is correct?

I personally think both are correct but have slightly different meaning which I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can’t believe he did that - I’ve never seen such bad behavior!

Here you don't use an article because you are using *behaviour* in its uncountable sense – referring to his behaviour in general.

You would use an article if you are referring to a specific behaviour:

> The gorilla adopted a dominant stance. This was a behaviour I had not seen before.

Comment: I'm nodding in front of my screen. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

behaviour is uncountable. You should not put 'a' before uncountable noun.

Comment: Thanks but I did some quick search and found that it could be either countable and uncountable :( Even the exact phrase "such a bad behavior" is usually found in Google results.

Comment: @NguyenM I think both are correct. *Such bad behavior* is also correct.

Comment: Such bad thing is different from Such a bad thing.

Comment: @Usernew with no difference at all?

Comment: @NguyenM Zero results for "such a bad behavior" on Google Ngram. It shows "such bad behavior" to be more common. However, Google search results favors the opposite!

Comment: @sotondolphin It was a mistake which is now corrected.

Comment: @NguyenM difference between what?

Comment: @Usernew between "such a bad" and "such bad"